# selenium python not working with phantomjs but works with Firefox

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am try to sort by most recent option using below code but it gives below error

**Error**

```
Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with css selector 'span.sortedLabel'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"107","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:34510","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"css selector\", \"value\": \"span.sortedLabel\", \"sessionId\": \"f5246520-f7d4-11e7-a9f4-adb0a497f49e\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/f5246520-f7d4-11e7-a9f4-adb0a497f49e/element"}}
```

Screenshot: available via screen

Everything works properly with Firefox, but not with phantomjs.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver  # open webdriver for specific browser
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  # for necessary browser action
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  # For selecting html code
import time

url="https://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-rent/residential-real-estate?proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment,Service-Apartment,Residential-House,Villa&Locality=Bellandur&cityName=Bangalore"
# os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = '127.0.0.1'
# driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'D:\Setup\NEW SOFTWARE\Python\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe')

driver.get(url)
try:
    #driver.find_element_by_id("sort4").click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.sortedLabel").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("sort4").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    html = driver.page_source
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Any solution to this ?

Comment: I have tried resizing the window size but still no luck. 
                                                                          driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)  # set browser size.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't implemented any timeouts. FF and PahntomJS might perform differently in terms of when a page is considered fully loaded and this can lead to a situation that FF works fine and PhantomJS does not. To quickly debug this behavior, just add few implicit waits between your cations and see if they help. If it works, replace the implicit waits with proper explicit waits.

An example of an implicit wait of 10 seconds:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added implicit waits before and after the click but still not working..